# How to write sqlite commands in a shell script?

Tags: scripting, sqlite

I want to write a shell script that firstly opens sqlite and then makes a copy of a table and finally deletes the contents of that table. How can I do it in a shell script?

```
>>cd /var/www/dbs
>>sqlite3 ha.db
sqlite>>.timeout 2000
sqlite>>INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2;
sqlite>>DELETE * FROM table2;
sqlite>>.quit
```

How to write this part?

```
>>sqlite3 ha.db
sqlite>>INSERT INTO table1 ('a1','a2') VALUES ('1','2');
sqlite>>.quit
```

Answer (score 9):

`sqlite3` reads commands from standard input, which means that you may feed it SQL from a file or from the command line and not just interactively. `sqlite3` will automatically exit at the end of input, so `.quit` is not necessary when using it non-interactively.

For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

sqlite3 /var/www/dbs/ha.db <<'END_SQL'
.timeout 2000
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2;
DELETE FROM table2;
END_SQL
```

Also notice the corrected syntax for the `DELETE`.

If you also need to create `table2` in the database:

```
#!/bin/sh

sqlite3 /var/www/dbs/ha.db <<'END_SQL'
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 AS SELECT * FROM table1;
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1;
DELETE FROM table1;
END_SQL
```

Change `DELETE FROM table1;` to `DROP table1;` if you need to delete `table1` completely (and not just its content).

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /var/www/dbs
echo ".timeout 2000
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2;
DELETE * FROM table2;
.quit" |
    sqlite3 ha.db
```

This only works if `sqlite3` reads from `stdin` and not from its `tty`.

Comment: Hi, I want to insert into a table in a shell script. When I write it as:  echo "INSERT INTO table1 ('a1','a2') VALUES ('1','2');
.quit" | sqlite3 ha.db    ,it issues errors that a1 and a2 are not found.What is wrong? and how can I write this?

Comment: @AhmadFatehi This is a new question that we can't answer unless we somehow also know the database schema for your `ha.db` database. If you have further issues with this, please ask a new question.